# can't see node_modules folder in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm, hidden

For some reason I can't see the `node_modules` folder. When I open the project on the explorer, the folder `node_modules` there so I'm 100% sure it's there. I tried to invalidate cache and restart PhpStorm and even deleting the `.idea` folder (which I don't see it too) it's still hidden. In the project settings I've already enabled the `Show Excluded Files` option. I tried to fresh install the program but it's still not shown.

How can I make the folder `node_modules` visible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a bug in the Vue plugin back in 2016. If you have installed the Vue plugin before Oct 4, 2016, you might have the bugged version installed that hides the `node_modules` folder.

The bugged Vue plugin was [removed](https://github.com/henjue/vue-for-idea/issues/46#issuecomment-251399568) from the plugin repository in Oct 4, 2016 and replaced with an official Vue plugin that does not cause this issue.

See https://github.com/henjue/vue-for-idea/issues/46.
If it's not the case, check if you have 'Show excluded files' enabled in Project tool window settings:

[image]

Comment: removing the Vue plugin seems to solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Hi just solved this issue as of PhpStorm@2022.1.1

In the Project tabs click on the cogwheel top left corner -> Tree Appearances -> Check Show Excluded Files.

This was my solution since I didn't have vue.js plugins installed and can't find the directory ignore that @Adriano Rosa mentioned.

Comment: This is the easiest solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For those people, like me, who doesn't have **Vue Plugin** installed and still not seeing the `node_modules` folder within your project, you may want to check if it is not ignored in:

`Settings > Editor > File Types`.

See my answer [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203372590/comments/115000133390)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For IntelliJ 2023 you have to go to “Project Options” > “Tree appearance” > “Show excluded files”

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If above solutions won't work try the show all files property (a small icon in the file explorer with an eye)

Answer (score 0):

delete .idea folder(the one comes with the IDE) and reopen it
works for me

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution: uncheck "Fold Root Files" in drop-down options menu (3 dots) of the project view.